# Create generalised update endpoint with Kotlin and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm working on a general CRUD controller for my Spring Boot app so that I don't have to implement crud methods for every resource. This is my function so far:

```
@PatchMapping(ENTITY_URL)
fun update(@PathVariable("id") entity: E,  @RequestBody fields: Map<String,Any>): E {
    entity::class.memberProperties
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
        .forEach { prop ->
            fields[prop.name]?.let {
                // Class.forName(prop.returnType.toString())
                val value = objectMapper.readValue(it.toString())
                prop.setter.call(entity,value)
            }
        }

    repo.save(entity)
    return entity
}
```

Before I was passing **it** directly to the setter and it worked fine for primitive types. The problem comes with more complicated properties. For example my user entity has a `roles` property of type `Set<Role>`. Of course spring does not know anything about my `fields`'s context so this `role:[{id:1}]` is transformed to an `ArrayList`.

What I was trying to do with the code above is to deserialise a field manually using the type of the property we work with but can't get it to work. The code as it is now obviously gives compile time error because it can not figure out the type, I know the second parameter can be a type but can't convert my type to a Java class. Also my set is of Kotlin Set not Java Set so `Class.forName` does not work either.

The I found the Kotlin module for the Object mapper and added it to my build.gradle.kt but still I can't figure out how to provide the type

Comment: Take a look at one of Spring's sub-projects - Spring Data REST (https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest)

Comment: Wow. Didn't know about this. Thanks